# Texto em movimento dentro de um textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de monitoramento e preciso pegar um texto de um arquivo de log e mostrar em uma tela de monitoramento.
Esse texto deve se mover dentro de textarea de cima para baixo.
Alguém sabe como devo proceder?

Comment: Seria bom editar a questão e por mais detalhes do que precisa que aconteça na prática. Da forma como está, vai depender do poder de adivinhação dos leitores. Sugestão de leitura para melhor aproveitamento do site: **[Ask]**. Para acrescentar mais detalhes na pergunta, basta usar o link **[edit]**.

Comment: Obrigado @Earendul.
Resolvido.
É que eu pensei que o `'marquee`' fosse apenas da direita para esquerda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar a tag [`marquee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) para esse fim. Por exemplo:

```html
<marquee direction="up" width="250" height="100" style="border:1px solid">
   Texto rolando
</marquee>
```

Porém, não é recomendado pois está [Deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) pelo W3C. Parece que a W3C está planejando criar um elemento direto no CSS para conseguir esse efeito, veja aqui http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/.

Também é acusado de ter problemas com desempenho, já que é beem antigo. Há alguns plugins que tentam resolver esse problema, como o https://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee

Você também pode usar CSS puro, que é mais recomendado pois não terá problemas de compatibilidade de *browser*. Um exemplo:

```css
.marquee {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;
     animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { margin-top: 100% }
    100% { margin-top: -10% }
}
@-moz-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { margin-top: 80% }
    100% { margin-top: -10% }
}
@-o-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { margin-top: 80% }
    100% { margin-top: -10% }
}
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { margin-top: 80% }
    100% { margin-top: -10% }
}
.quadro {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="quadro">
  <p class="marquee">Testando</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou.