# Como fazer busca em um slide de movimentação de texto

Tags: jquery, html5

Gostaria de saber como se chama esse tipo de [efeito](http://www.ufpa.br/dicas/htm/htm-efet.htm)
se derem uma olhada verão textos indo da esquerda par direita e vice-versa porem já pesquisei e só acho slides não sei como fazer um filtro de pesquisa pois não sei qual o nome que dão para esse tipo de efeito

Comment: É utilizado a tag `marquee` para isso, mas ela está obsoleta. Aqui tem algo parecido e como é feito: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43805/14674

Comment: amigo coloca como resposta apara eu dar como aceita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O efeito utilizado no site que você referenciou é feito usando a tag [`marquee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee). Mas se atente que ela está **obsoleta** e pode não funcionar nos *browsers* atuais.

Um exemplo do funcionamento dele:

```html
<marquee direction="right" width="250" height="100" style="border:1px solid">
   Texto rolando
</marquee>
```

Mais informações: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43805/14674

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda